Noncommutative 3-dimensional associative algebra over a finite field
Let $F$ be a finite field. Does there exist a noncommutative 3-dimensional associative algebra $A$ over $F$?
Since $A$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $F$ is finite, $A$ is finite. By Wedderburn's little theorem, if $A$ is a division ring, then $A$ would be commutative. Thus, $A$ is not a division ring.
Attempt:
I tried producing such an algebra by the following general procedure: choose a finite group $G$, find an ideal $I\subseteq FG$ (where $FG$ is the group algebra) then obtain $A$ as the quotient $FG/I$.
Indeed, the quaternion algebra can be obtained in this way. Let $G=Q_8$, and let $t\in Q_8$ be the unique (central) involution. Let $R=FG$, where $F$ is any field at all. Then $R/(t+1)R$ is the quaternion algebra over $F$.
For $G=S_3$, $FG$ does not have any three-dimensional quotients in general.
Motivation:
My goal is to prove that in every finite field, $-1$ is a sum of two squares. I have already seen a proof of this which uses a counting argument, but just for fun, I want to prove it in the following way:
Construct a three-dimensional noncommutative $F$-algebra $A$. Let $\{1,i,j\}$ be an $F$-basis for $A$, with respect to which there is a norm that is a sum of three squares: that is to say, for each $x=a+bi+cj$, there is some $\overline{x}$ such that $x\overline{x}=a^2+b^2+c^2$, where $a,b,c\in F$.
Since $A$ cannot be a division ring, there must be some $a,b,c\in F$ (with $abc\neq 0$) such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=0$. Without loss of generality, suppose $c\neq 0$. Then $(a/c)^2+(b/c)^2=-1$, as desired.

What about the $2 \times 2$ triangular algebra? Over $F_p$, it is the only noncommutative (unital!) ring of order $p^3$ as shown by Raghavendran "Finite associative rings" (1969), theorem 14.

Oh! Thanks, let me see if it has a sum-of-three-square norm

We can construct a $3$-dimensional associative noncommutative algebra over any field, in particular over any finite field.
(However, it will be non-unital, but associative algebras need not be unital).
Let $K$ be an arbitrary field and $V$ be a $K$-vector space with basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$.
Define a $K$-algebra product on this basis as follows:
$$
e_1\cdot e_1=e_1,\; e_1\cdot e_2=e_3,\; e_1\cdot e_3=e_3,
$$
and all other products equal to zero. Clearly $A=(V,\cdot)$ is noncommutative, because $e_2\cdot e_1=0\neq e_3=e_1\cdot e_2$. Also, it is associative and has dimension $3$ over $K$.

The OP has $1$ in the $F$-basis for the algebra, I think unital algebras were implied (they also make use of an injection $F \hookrightarrow A$).

@Amateur_Algebraist Yes, this might be the case. However, associative algebras need not be unital.

May I ask how you came up with this?

I have a classification of all $3$-dimensional associative algebras (commutative and non-commutative).
